# Remembering the PI angles

Tags: geometry, pi

What is a good way to remember the essential angles from the unit circle?
For instance $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \text{ and } \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
[image: Unit circle with important angles]

Comment: You need only remember $\sin(x)$ for the angles in the region $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ from there it is the rest of the trig relations

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553990/easy-way-of-memorizing-values-of-sine-cosine-and-tangent/1554126#1554126

Comment: @Alex5207 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi - Thanks, it was definitely solved - How can I set as solved?

Comment: There should be a button somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex5207 Take a look here. Thanks! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: @Alex5207 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the most effective way is to memorize the important ones in the first quadrant and then obtain the others by symmetry.

Comment: In fact you could just memorize the ones in the first octant $(0 \le \theta \le \pi/4)$ and get the rest by symmetry.