# Problem in memorizing Trigonometry Table

Tags: trigonometry

I just started with Trigonometry and I am finding it difficult to memorize the Trigonometry Table. Due to this I am unable to solve sums without referring the table. Is any trick/way to memorize the Trigonometry Table. Thanks in advance

Comment: That question is off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way of memorizing values of sine, cosine, and tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553990/easy-way-of-memorizing-values-of-sine-cosine-and-tangent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sin 0^\circ, \sin 30^\circ, \sin 45^\circ, \sin 60^\circ, \text{and} \sin90^\circ$ equal to $\sqrt{\frac{0}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}, \text{and} \sqrt{\frac{4}{4}}$ respectively.

For $\cos\theta$ from $0^\circ \text{to } 90^\circ$, it is just the reverse order: $\sqrt{\frac{4}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{4}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}, \text{and} \sqrt{\frac{0}{4}}$

For $\tan\theta$, you can just divide sine and cosine: $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$

For $\csc\theta, \sec\theta, \text{and} \cot\theta$, you can just take the reciprocals of sine, cosine, and tangent respectively.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. This trick will really help me in the future for solving sums. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Remember these two pictures then use the definition of $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$ in a right angled triangle

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!